# Process GET in Symfony-Form is always empty

Tags: forms, symfony

I try to implement a searchform in my Symfony-Application. POST works fine, but I want to use `/search?q=foo`. I have a form with `method=GET` but I can't bind my Request to the Form with the following Request:

`search?form%5B_token%5D=HC5M4nG-B-r5BUUSmCchkryqNQyu9RvDDlTvcTDuFFY&form%5Bq%5D=foobar`

This is my Form

```
$data = array();
return $this->createFormBuilder($data)
    ->add('q', 'text')
    ->getForm();
```

And the current Controller

```
/**
 * @var $form Form
 */
$form = $this->getSearchForm();

if ($request->isMethod('GET')) {
    // contains q = 'foobar'
    dump($_GET);
    // null
    dump($request->request->get('q'));
    // null
    dump($request->request->get('form'));

    $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));
    $form->handleRequest($request);


    $data = $form->getData();
    // null
    dump($data);

    ...
}
```

the form-template

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('search'), 'method': 'GET', 'attr': { 'class' : 'navbar-form navbar-left', 'role' : 'search' }}) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.q) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.q) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.q, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'Find' }}) }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Find</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$request->request->all()` is all of the `$_POST` parameters.

`$request->query->all()` is all of the `$_GET` parameters.

You should be using `$request->query->get('q')` or `$request->get('a')` (which will go through each of the parameter bags) to get your parameters.

For more info see [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#accessing-request-data).

Comment: Thank you. I did not see the wood for the trees